# Need an assist with a deployment diagram

Tags: deployment, uml, deployment-diagram

I have a school project with 3 parts. One of them is to make a deployment diagram of the following scenario:
A railway company got a new information system that enables customers to buy tickets and to check-in. At first release, the customers need to call the railway's customer services and do those thing via the dispacher. Second release- the customers can do those things via a web site, last release- via an app.
One a day, the system updates the data base.
I have made a deployment diagram that I thik is OK, but I want to get some suggestions.
Also, which protocol is used to connect with the database server from the regular server?
(the link to the diagram ->)
[The Diagram](https://rapidshare.com/#!download%7C475p2%7C4291495907%7CDeployment%20Diagram.jpg%7C114%7C1260%7C993%7C1%7Creferer-BE108F372378A84D91ACDF7D020DD4EE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layers will be on same machine or different machine/server?
if its on same we need not to worry about protocol we will access via localhost only

If you have different servers you need to use SSL as well, there are lot of service provider which provides mysql online via ssl